# Histogram as scatter plot

Tags: plotting, histograms

I want to draw a histogram as scatter plot, i.e. bin center vs. count. I found only a cumbersome way (steps 1-4) to achieve this standard procedure. Is there a more efficient way to draw a bin-centered scatter histogram for given bin number?

**0.** Create data for demonstration

`data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10000];`

**1.** Create `bins` and `counts` of histogram with defined number of bins

`{bins, counts} = HistogramList[data, 100, "PDF"];`

**2.** The variable `bins` contains the left bin border and of course the data point shall be at the bin center, so we have to add half of the bin width

`bins = bins + Abs[bins[[1]] - bins[[2]]]/2;`

**3.** Add place holder to `counts` as `bins` contains 1 more value than `counts`

`counts = Append[counts, 0];`

**4.** Reshape data

`datadisplay = Transpose[{bins, counts}];`

**5.** Plot histogram

`ListPlot[datadisplay]`

All together:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10000];
{bins, counts} = HistogramList[data, 100, "PDF"];
bins += Abs[bins[[1]] - bins[[2]]]/2;
counts = Append[counts, 0];
datadisplay = Transpose[{bins, counts}];
ListPlot[datadisplay]
```

[image]

MMA 12.3

Comment: Seems a bad idea to draw a histogram as a scatterplot this way. If anything, I'd scatter representatives of the actual data points, _under_ the histogram (with random y values within the range).

Comment: I also think it's hard to understand why would you want to do what you ask, but for a different reason. For me, *Histograms* applied to continuous variables are a tool that belongs in the past when computation was expensive, and they should be considered obsolete. Introducing an arbitrary parameter like the *bin size* and artificially discretizing a continuous variable seems like a bad idea when you can directly deal with `EmpiricalDistribution`  and `FindDistributionParameters`. At the very least probably you may want to use a continuous Kernel Density plot, like `SmoothHistogram`.

Comment: Smoothing manipulates the histogram shape at locations of sharp changes in the population and pretends that the real histogram follows the smoothed curve. Points show the counts only for the bin and is more serious.

Comment: What do you mean by *"is more serious"*? There is no *"real histogram"*, if the underlying PDF has a "sharp" feature it will also be distorted by binning unless you shift the bins by hand to coincide with the sharp feature. A histogram is just a special case of Kernel density with values rounded and a top-hat kernel, both very unrealistic choices. Choosing Kernels that reflect the expected uncertainty of the data collected makes way more sense.

Comment: If you smooth by a function then you have to add the function and a width and the result is not easy to understand. The smoothing function and definition of width can be arbitrarily defined. If you just smooth a bin constantly and you add the bin width then everybody understands.

Comment: I can't agree with that but probably this is not the place for this discussion. We have different perspectives, let's leave it there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `ChartElementFunction -> "Point"` to get *a histogram as a scatter plot* in one step:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10000];

Histogram[data, 100, "PDF", ChartElementFunction -> "Point", 
 ChartStyle -> ColorData[97][1], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Add the options `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"` and `ChartBaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[7]` to get

[image]

**Note:** Re ***"Is there a more efficient way ..."***: Working with `HistogramList` and using the resulting coordinates with `ListPlot` or `Graphics` is faster than using `Histogram`. Furthermore, `Histogram` does not render bars with zero height; so, if you need to display those points, then `HistogramList` is the only way to go:

```
histogram = Histogram[data, 100, "PDF", ChartElementFunction -> "Point", 
     ChartStyle -> Red, 
     ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], AbsolutePointSize[8]], 
     ImageSize -> Large]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.055

```
listplot = ListPlot[
     Transpose @ MapAt[MovingAverage[#, 2] &, 
       HistogramList[data, 100, "PDF"], {1}], 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Green, AbsolutePointSize[5]]]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.024

```
graphics = Graphics[{Directive[Opacity[1], Black, AbsolutePointSize[2]], 
      Point @ Transpose @ MapAt[MovingAverage[#, 2] &, 
         HistogramList[data, 100, "PDF"], {1}]}]; // 
  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.004

```
Legended[Show[histogram, listplot, graphics], 
   PointLegend[{Red, Green, Black},
     {"Histogram", "ListPlot", "Graphics"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Do these methods place the point in the bin center? Else it would be wrong.

Comment: @granularbastard, yes they do.